# Design a matrix to reflect a signal

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, complex-multiplication

I have a signal $R$, can be thought of a vector of say 10,000 samples (created by taking magnitude of complex values).

I have two more signals $T_1$ and $T_2$ (exact copy) each with 10,000 samples, which can be thought of a matrix of shape $[2_{rows} \times 1_{ col}]$ of complex valued for each samples (contains both magnitude and phase).

Now, I want to change the signals $T_1$ and $T_2$ by multiplying with a $2 \times 2$ matrix $U$, in such a way that it reflects $R$ in both of its output rows.

Can anyone give me an idea how to design the matrix $U$ so the phase and amplitude of $T_s$ will be changed in similar manner as $R$ ?

Adding an image for better understanding:][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSM72.jpg)

Trying to make things clearer as asked below:

$T_1 = [1+1j]$ ; 
$T_2 = [1+1j]$ ;
$R = [3+2j]$

Now think $T_1$ and $T_2$ as a two vectors input to a matrix $U$ which is $2 \times 2$, which will have output $X_1$ and $X_2$ where $X_1 = [3+2j]$ and $X_2 = [3+2j]$

Comment: Maybe a numerical example (with 10,000 replaced by 4) would make what you want clearer to us?

Comment: I have added an image for better understanding

Comment: Still not clear what's your aim. Could you provide an example with actual numbers?